# html to generate a graph of certain data stored externally

Tags: javascript, html, excel, graph

I wasn't completely sure what to name this, so hopefully I did an okay job.

Im designing the website for a shooting club, and I want a page where people can put in their 'code' and a graph of their scores will display. I have all of the scores stored in an Excel file, and Im unsure of how to make this work?

I need some sort of code to pull the results from the database, and display them in a graph but only after the user has input their code. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a look at Google Charts (https://developers.google.com/chart/)

It's javascript and html based as you're asking, and I've used it in different applications with millions of data points without problems.

You could let the users input their data and then redirect to a simple page incorporating a Google Chart showing their results graphically.

If you're writing to the Excel file from a web form, reading it should be easy for you too. Otherwise more information about your setup is needed.

For a more specific answer, please feel free to post a more specific question.